# Competitors of Urban Airship for In-App purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm currently developing an ibook app with a reader (that is entirely functional nowadays), and an ibook store. I can't develop the ibook store from scratch and maintaining a dedicated server. So I would like to use an external service that could help me to submit my application in a shorter time.

I've seen that Urban Airship propose a service for in-app purchase. Is there any other competitor? Do you think that this could really help in my case? Do you have a feedback of Urban Airship?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I know Parse has in-app purchase and it's free for 1,000,000 API request as well as Push notification and lots of other features.

https://parse.com/plans

You can also read this tutorial to see how it works for basics:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/19341/how-to-easily-create-a-web-backend-for-your-apps-with-parse

and this one to see other backend providers:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more